# Opening Excel file from Server aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following X.aspx  code..to download excel file from Server

```
if (ss[5] != "")
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-disposisition", "inline;filename=x.xls");
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.TransmitFile(ss[5]);
                Response.End();
            }
```

Excel throws message

The file you are trying to open 'x.aspx', is in a different format that specified by the file extention....

How can I let excel know the correct file name ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo in your content disposition header.  Try:

`Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=x.xls");`

or

`Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=x.xls");`

Comment: Thanks David, it is indeed a typo corrected as sugessted and working fine ..

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?